# Can you differentiate between channels in dialogflow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

In other words, can I have different paths to take depending on whether the user is interacting with IVR, SMS, Web? Or do I write one experience that's being used in every single channel?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be possible, still it's not something that is natively provided by Google I guess.
Some suggestions as to how I would approach something like this:

1. Create a single agent.
   When the bot is triggered externally make sure to instantiate a custom parameter, for example *source* = ivr/sms/web. Then, for those sections of the flow you want customised, you could create additional pages and route to the correct one based on intent + $session.params.source = whatever you want. [these are the session parameters you can define at runtime](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#session)
2. Create one agent, complete all configurations, then create another agent for another channel and import the other one. At this point you can connect each agent to a specific channel and (keeping the general structure) personalise answers/paths without having to create ghost-parallel pages. [here you can find instructions for importing/exporting agents.](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#export) Please note that importing an agent will reset any progress made and overwrite it with the version you're importing.
3. The third option is to do this via webhooks. First, you can do the parameter setting of list item n°1. Then, for each section of the flow you want to personalise you should call a webhook and use an conditional block to determine the channel and offer the proper response.
4. Alternatively, and I just mention this because I read it's possible, although I didn't actually ever try it, you could take advantage of versioning. In practice, you can "save" an agent at a given time by means of a version-environment (let's say, for the web version), and then you can edit the conversation flows you want to customize and save another separate version to a separate environment. Then, you can connect the web interface to the correct environment (which you can then update/edit by selecting it) and the IVR to a different environment with different conversation flows. [this is the relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/version)